# Convert a single character in the URL during htaccess Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to convert a single lowercase letter into an uppercase letter during rewrite in .htaccess. For example, I have this

URL: `www.domain.com/?country=CUoatia`

and I wanted it to become: `www.domain.com/Croatia`

In addition, the uppercase letter 'U' will be converted to 'r'.

I can achieve `www.domain.com/CUoatia` using the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^country=(.*)
RewriteRule ^$ %1? [R=301]
```

But I do not know how to change that 'U' character to 'r'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing your rules around to:

```
# Replace all capital U in query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)U(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1r%2  [L]

# Make sure there are no capital U in the query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !U
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^country=(.*)
RewriteRule ^$ %1? [R=301]
```